# R - What is MLE and MME from logistic regression

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I stumbled upon this chunk of code but I'm not sure what MME is (last line), especially how 0.577216 is derived and what is it for? (I guess MLE is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator)

```
y <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
x <- c(53, 57, 58, 63, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 72, 73, 75, 75,
       76, 76, 78, 79, 81)
# Preliminary output from ML estimation
logreg.out <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial(logit))
summary(logreg.out)
a.mle <- as.numeric(logreg.out$coefficients[1])
b.mle <- as.numeric(logreg.out$coefficients[2])
var.a.mle <- summary(logreg.out)$cov.scaled[1, 1]
var.b.mle <- summary(logreg.out)$cov.scaled[2, 2]
b.mme <- exp(a.mle + 0.577216)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant.  It's crucial to let non-R users know that `family=binomial(logit)` means, among other things, that the logit function is used for the link.

Comment: The exponential of the coefficients gives the odds. I have no idea where the 0.577 comes from